# placing for-loop i in div

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I have a script that changes the background color and plays a sound based on the user input. The sounds and color-change happens based on the length of the input. I also have a div where I want to show the letter that is making the change, i from the for-loop. So the div content, i, would also change with every click and color-change. If the user input is "hello", the div content should change one by one from h to e, to l, to l, to o. I have this but of course it only shows how long the input. I would appreciate any help.

```
document.getElementById('icard').innerHTML = i;
```

[jsBin](http://jsbin.com/hujixote/2/edit?html,output)

Comment: Take a look at [jQuery html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/).

Comment: Do you mean something like this: http://jsbin.com/hujixote/11/edit ? I only added `document.getElementById('icard').innerHTML = i+ " - " + entry;` (the "+ entry" part)

Comment: @ReGdYN As aka likes your comment how about adding it as an answer to show that this question has an accepted answer for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

`list3` contains the array of your characters. So you need to select the character at the index of the loop:

```
 document.getElementById('icard').innerHTML = list3[i];
```

Comment: Each loop through 'for' will replace the result with the next character and it will just end up with the last character.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your final code. I fixed it. Happy Coding!!

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <style>
    body{background:#ccc;}
    </style>
</head>

<body>  

        <form name="name1" method="post" id="name1">
        <select class="select1" id="selectid" name="selectuser" onChange='Choice();'>
        <option>Your text</option>
        <option value="1">English</option>
        <option value="2">French</option>
        <option value="3">German</option>
        <option value="4">Turkish</option>
        <option value="5">Slovak</option>
        <option value="6">Spanish</option>
        </select>
        <input class="input1" id="ids" name="id" onkeyup="getVal()" type="text"  o>
        <input type="button" value="Submit" name="B1" onclick="getText()">
        </form>  

    <div id="icard" class="drag" style="left: 0px; top: 0px; width:10%;  height:10%;"></div>
    <audio id="audio">
    <source src='http://www.mediacollege.com/downloads/sound-effects/hit/hit-01.wav' type="audio/mpeg" />
    </audio>
    <audio id="audio2">
    <source src='http://www.mediacollege.com/downloads/sound-effects/hit/hit-pipe.wav' type="audio/mpeg" />
    </audio>



    <script language="JavaScript">

    function getText() {
    var myString = document.name1.ids.value.toLowerCase();
    var list3 = myString.split('')
    var list1 = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0"];
    var list2 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', "ı", 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'];


    for (var i = 0; i < list3.length; i++) {

       setTimeout(playOne.bind(null, list3[i]), i*550,j=i);
        //document.getElementById('icard').innerHTML = i;
        //document.body.style.backgroundColor = '#' + //Math.random().toString(16).slice(2, 8);


    }

    function playOne(entry,j) {

        if (list1.indexOf(entry) >= 0) {
           setTimeout(audio.play(null, list1[i]), i*550);
            document.getElementById('icard').innerHTML = j+1;
            document.body.style.backgroundColor = '#' + Math.random().toString(16).slice(2, 8);


        } else if (list2.indexOf(entry) >= 0) {
           setTimeout(audio2.play(null, list2[i]), i*550);
            document.getElementById('icard').innerHTML = j+1;
            document.body.style.backgroundColor = '#' + Math.random().toString(16).slice(2, 8);
        }
    }
}

    </script> 

    <script>
    var ids = new Array();
    ids[0] = "";
    ids[1] = "hello";
    ids[2] = "salut";
    ids[3] = "hallo";
    ids[4] = "merhaba";
    ids[5] = "ahoy";
    ids[6] = "ola";
            function Choice() {
                y = document.getElementById("selectid");
                  document.getElementById("ids").value = ids[y.selectedIndex];
             }
    </script>

    <script>
    var audio = document.getElementById('audio');
    var audio2 = document.getElementById('audio2');
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

So overall, I just passed iteration index to function and capture the same. That's It

Comment: Your answer would be more helpful if you **explained** *what* was wrong and *how* you fixed. Posting a code dump only doesn't have any long lasting value.